# How do I get the html character code to show properly

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

Good day.
I am trying to figure out why a certain html dec code will not display on a ipad.
The character in question is `&#119184;`
Strangely, it works on my PC in all browsers, works on my Android phone in chrome but will not work on my ipad in either Chrome or Safari.

I have checked the files for UTF-8 encoding and all is good.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It possible problem with font type

Comment: Interesting.  I have changed the font-family to Arial.

Comment: The encoding doesn’t even matter - _because_ you are using a numeric entity.

Comment: Looking it up online, it doesn't show up on my MacBook. It may not be an available code on Apple systems. In fact, none of the codes on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Unicode_chart_Musical_Symbols show up.

Comment: Also, very few on https://www.alt-codes.net/music_note_alt_codes.php show for me

Comment: @aynber that is exactly where I was getting them from.  Maybe I can't use them after all?  That would be unfortunate.

Comment: One site suggest downloading another font such as Maestro that may have it. But that won't help much on a website unless you provide the font for all users. Other than that, maybe use images instead of unicodes